# matplotlib installation on OS X doesn't support 64 bit architecture

Tags: python, macos, numpy, matplotlib

Alright, so after reinstalling my os my python installation died. Python, numpy and ipython work fine, but matplotlib has misteriously vanished. After repeatedly trying to install it from macports, egg, and others, I have managed to do it through their provided .dmg. Now apparently, matplotlib doesn't support 64 bit architecture (?????). Anyway, though maybe someone here had been through a similar problem. So, my specs: MAC OS x 10.7.2, python 2.7 out of the box, numpy 1.5.1 and matplotlib 1.1.0. Here's the output:

> File "", line 1, in 
>    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site->packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 23, in 
>      from matplotlib.figure import Figure, figaspect
>    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site->packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 16, in 
>      import artist
>    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site->packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 6, in 
>      from transforms import Bbox, IdentityTransform, TransformedBbox, TransformedPath
>    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site->packages/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 34, in 
>      from matplotlib._path import affine_transform
>   ImportError: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site->packages/matplotlib/_path.so: no appropriate 64-bit architecture (see "man python" for >running in 32-bit mode)

Thanks for any help, please let me know if I'm posting this absolutely in the wrong place!

Alex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hit the same problem and never managed to fix it.

If you work in academia or are a student then there is a free version of the Enthought Python Distribution (EPD) available - that's what I used in the end and it has been excellent.
http://enthought.com/products/edudownload.php

It has python, matplotlib, numpy, scipy, and many other packages precompiled, and has an OSX 64 bit version.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative. I've actually resorted to a binary backup, which worked pretty well. I'll check the distribution though. I believe for the future I'll try to always install the whole python shbang into my home directory as a user, not into the system library as superuser. That's the "right" thing to do I think.

Comment: And by the way, I just went with calling ffmpeg directly through os.system calls, which is pretty stupid, but it's the way I managed!